# What does "constant proportionality" mean in simple words?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I read this sentence from algorithm book:

**The reason is that any split of constant proportionality yields a recursion tree of depth O(lg n).**

What does mean by "constant proportionality" in a simple words?

[image]

Comment: You might get more relevant answers if you ask on a cs/math site because this is a technical question. That said, 'constant proportion' is not an idiom - it means 'same ratio'. The theorem works as shown in the picture for 1/2, but also for 1/3, 3/8, any ratio, which is the same as 'constant proportion'. Why mention 'constant'? Because sometimes a split could be $n-1$ and 1 (not a ratio) which would give a runtime of $O(n^2)$, or it could be  $\sqrt(n)$ groups of size $\sqrt(n)$ (not a -constant- ratio) for $O(n \g \lg n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quicksort, the "Big O" is the same, `n lg n` whether the binary tree is balanced or not. While `n lg n` makes sense if the tree is perfectly symmetrical, it *also* appears if the tree is highly asymmetrical (in the text, 99:1), as long as there is a *constant proportion* of asymmetricality (that is, all subtrees are 99:1).

Comment: Yes, equally balanced. But the *constant proportionality* is referencing equally *unbalanced* as well.